# How can I change color of bootstrap progress bar with custom color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I change the color of a Bootstrap progress bar without losing the text? I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9952446/1813169):

```js
$('#pb').css({
    'background-image': 'none',
    'background-color': 'red'
});
```

It works, but I lose any text in the progress bar.

Comment: What version ow Twitter Bootstrap are you using? In v3.2.0 there's no background-image any more, so you only need to change the background-color. Do you have a fiddle to see how is that text disappearing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using Bootstrap 3.2.0, you can do something like the following:

```js
$(function() { 
   $("#one").addClass("progress-bar-purple");
   $("#two").addClass("progress-bar-orange");
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-purple {
      background-color: purple !important;
}
.progress-bar-orange {
      background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div class="progress">
  <div id="one" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    60%
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div id="two" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
    80%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

Simplest thing you can do is...

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%; background-color:red !important;">
    </div>
</div>
```

mention style="width:10%; background-color:red !important;" in progress-bar div

put any color instead of red...

Comment: Worked for me without needing the !important.

Answer (score 5):

These two lines are directly from the Bootstrap CSS

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #007bff;
}

.progress-bar-striped {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 1rem 1rem;
}
```

Simply use these in your html, between `<style></style>` or in a css-file that you load after you load bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap sass, it has a mixin that you can include like this:

```
.progress {
  @include progress-bar-variant(#000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that bootstrap in the year in which the question was asked was different, but now you have the possibility to add bootstrap classes that provide the color.

```css
.progress{
    margin:10px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Normal -->
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<!-- Striped -->
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<!-- Animated stripes -->
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
</div>
```

> There are a variety of colors which you [can find
>   here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/), and you
>   will find colors for the text and for the background.