# How to Change Color of Progress Bar Angular Directive

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I want to integrate angular progress directive in my application.

I found progress bar directive that solve the purpose but I'm not able to change the color of progress bar. I want to give custom color for progress bar.

Does anyone have any idea on this ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ProgressDemoCtrl">

    <h3>Static</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><progressbar value="55"></progressbar></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><progressbar class="progress-striped" value="22" type="warning">22%</progressbar></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><progressbar class="progress-striped active" max="200" value="166" type="danger"><i>166 / 200</i></progressbar></div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <h3>Dynamic <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="random()">Randomize</button></h3>
    <progressbar max="max" value="dynamic"><span style="color:black; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}</span></progressbar>

    <small><em>No animation</em></small>
    <progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{dynamic}}%</b></progressbar>

    <small><em>Object (changes type based on value)</em></small>
    <progressbar class="progress-striped active" value="dynamic" type="{{type}}">{{type}} <i ng-show="showWarning">!!! Watch out !!!</i></progressbar>

    <hr />
    <h3>Stacked <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="randomStacked()">Randomize</button></h3>
    <progress><bar ng-repeat="bar in stacked track by $index" value="bar.value" type="{{bar.type}}"><span ng-hide="bar.value < 5">{{bar.value}}%</span></bar></progress>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Plunker Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/3AIJPQzQgosmlXV3QQ9D?p=preview

Comment: There are so many bars, which bar color change would you need?

Answer (score 10):

Extending [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219670/how-can-i-change-color-of-bootstrap-progress-bar-with-custom-color), you can change the color of a [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Progressbar using the following "hacky" method:

```
<uib-progressbar value="10" type="purple"></uib-progressbar>
```

this will generate a class
`.progress-bar-purple`

which you can define as a css rule

```
.progress-bar-purple {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color from a predefined one to another by changing the `type` attribute of the `<progressbar/>` directive.

```
<progressbar class="progress-striped" value="22" type="warning">22%</progressbar>
```

From the doc:

> (Default: null) : Style type. Possible values are 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger'.

Then you can customize these colors by directly overriding them in your project source code or by generating a custom build in [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#colors)