# progress bar color doesn't change at all

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I am using the `Progress bar` from `react-bootstrap` but I can't change the color of the progressbar. it remains blue.

I tried to use `color` or `background-color` in the css but nothing change.

[image]

`<ProgressBar max={maxPages} now={step+1} bsPrefix="progress-bar-test" />`

css is

```
.progress-bar-test {
  color: #ff7255; 
}
```

Any idea ?? I am lost

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219670/how-can-i-change-color-of-bootstrap-progress-bar-with-custom-color/26224379

Comment: You may need to use `!important` (the answers Mitulat linked do that)

Comment: @BasvanderLinden `background-color` is not working as change the background and the progress bar

Comment: @Seb I should've clarified, I meant using background-color and !important using the .progress-bar selector instead of .progress-bar-test. But `95faf8e76605e973` is right that using css specificity is better than relying on `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not listen to the comments section. You must avoid using `!important` whenever possible as this can be a headache to maintain. You can increase your CSS specificity for this.

```
<ProgressBar now={60} className="orange-progress-bar" />

.orange-progress-bar .progress-bar {
  background-color: #ff7255;
}
```

[image: Edit sweet-volhard-6w4d9]