# How to change the bootstrap progress bar text color as the bar fills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I have a bootstrap progress bar which I am filling dynamically based on a percentage calculation I am doing. I also have a span element in the progress bar div. 
My code looks something like this:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" id="progress12"
        role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" style="width:50%"></div>
   <span class="progressText">progresstext</span>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.progressText {
    position: inherit;
}
```

So when the progress bar is filled 50%, I want half of the text to be in one color and other half which is not in the fill to be another color.

Is there any way I can change the color of the text dynamically as the progress bar updates?

Comment: Would you like to use the built in progress bar types/colors, or to use a custom "green, red, blue" color? You can use Jquery/js to change the CSS and update it.

Comment: I am using the built in css colors for the progress bar fill which come with bootstrap. I am more interested to know a way to change the color of the progressText based on the background fill color. 
for example: if the progress bar is 50% filled with blue strips the text in this area should be white and the remaining 50% which is not filled, the text should be black

Comment: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952446/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-bootstrap-twitter-progress-bar-at-runtime

Comment: You better make a custom progress bar for your own. Since modifying and using progress bar of bootstrap is not a good option for you. Try to create a custom progress bar.