# Change background image of bootstrap progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add a background image to my progress bar in bootstrap. Is this possible? My html is:

```
<div class="progress" style="margin-top:3%;">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%; 
background-image:url(scribble.png);">
<span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Related but not duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952446/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-bootstrap-twitter-progress-bar-at-runtime) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219670/how-can-i-change-color-of-bootstrap-progress-bar-with-custom-color).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to modify the **.progress** and **.progressBar** classes.

```
<style>
.progress {
      margin-top: 3%;
      background-color: rgba(32,127,225,.6);
}
.progress-bar {
      width: 70%;
      background-image:url(scribble.png)
}
</style>
```

***Avoid inline style attributes*** because they make it very difficult to maintain the code.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I had the wrong code. Check again. I want to change the background-image to scribble.png